# Will two rooms crossing diagonally count as one room?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If I build two bedrooms like this:

```
WWWWWWW
WWOOODW
WOWWWWW
WOWWWWW
WOWWWWW
WDWWWWW
WWWWWWW
```

W - Wall, O - Empty Space, D - Door

Will these rooms treat as one? Will two dwarves sleeping here think they are sleeping with others?

Comment: That depends how you define the rooms. Having an open space next to a room will decrease its value, but I don't think there will be a problem with this.

Comment: The best thing about these diagonal rooms is that miasma does not spread diagonally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A room in Dwarf Fort is defined by whatever you're assigning, whether that be a study, bedroom, etc... You could make a giant hall composed of several "bedrooms" by defining each bedroom a specific small area of that hall. You also can expand through diagonal spaces, so you could technically define it as one room by simply expanding through both. You could also define it as two overlapping rooms if you want as well.

You can define multiple overlapping rooms. The value of any tile is divided among all the rooms that the tile shares. So if your tile has a value of 600 and 2 rooms share it, then each room gets a 300 value bonus from it.

Either way you look at it, it will never be treated as any number of rooms less than you defined it. If you want it to be 2 rooms, then the game will treat them as two rooms. If you want 30 1-tile rooms, then the game will let you.

Comment: This answer is missing one thing - whether or not he'd be allowed to define it as just a single room.  Which I think is what he's tryign to get at - whereas your answer seems to suggest that he'll have to define it as at least two.

Comment: So "room" does not have to be a completely closed area? Thank you for your answer, it's very informative.

Comment: Correct, though you don't get value bonuses from the walls.